# select() function fails in winsock

Tags: c, select, winsock, winsock2

I am making a udp client. And I am using select function to implement timeouts :

```
            FD_ZERO(&stReadFDS);
            FD_SET(clientSock, &stReadFDS);
            int t = select(1, &stReadFDS, NULL, NULL, &sTimeOut);//first parameter of select is ignored in winsocks
            if (t = SOCKET_ERROR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Call to select() failed");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (t != 0) {

                if (FD_ISSET(clientSock, &stReadFDS)) {
           //recvfrom(...)
                 }
            }
```

every time select func returns a SOCKET_ERROR.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should post more code , the problem may be in the socket setup

Comment: I dont think so. Because when I remove the select and write recvfrom instead of it, it works

Comment: Is your sTimeOut set to a reasonable value?  e.g. if it is set to a negative value, select() may fail.  Keep in mind also that sTimeOut may be changed by a call to select(), so it's usually necessary to explicitly set it to the correct value again each time you call select().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple typo:

```
if (t = SOCKET_ERROR)
```

should be:

```
if (t == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Comment: After 15 hours coding, I missed that detail.Then I realized that. But thank you anyway

Comment: Always compile with full warnings enabled.  I'm pretty sure this line would show up as a warning.

Comment: I am using gcc and it didn't unfortunately

Comment: With `gcc -Wall`, I got this warning: `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`.